# ReportViewer page break on wrong page and generate unnecessary pages

Tags: c#, reportviewer, rdlc

I am learning to create report viewer application. I have about 14 rows. For each 7 rows I am putting page break. But When I click on "Print Layout" to see the print preview , the first page has first 7 rows then **next 3-4 page just blank** and then again last 7 rows. In total it is always generating 6 pages.

To page break on specific rows I have tried:

- [How to page break after specific row(Suppose 25 rows) in rdlc reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467997/how-to-page-break-after-specific-rowsuppose-25-rows-in-rdlc-reporting)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/253b76b8-d577-432b-b352-11a3c91fb8c6/limit-matrix-row-number-per-page?forum=sqlreportingservices (Reply of Tom Willwerth) .

Why it is happening and how I can fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your report is not too wide. If it is, the excess is put on the next page or pages.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not think about this before!

Comment: @j-h, Is it possible to include the full table design like merged cell/rows for each page break (break after 7 rows)? Should i post another question for this?